# iOS xCode 13 - App can't access downloaded files via "Open in..." sharing option

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode13

When implementing ["Open in.." feature](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1587/_index.html) via the file sharing options, app cannot access the downloaded files at "File Provider Storage", `FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)` returns `false` although the file exists, at the same time in the system console there are logs like

```
Sandbox: FileAccessIssueA(11544) deny(2) file-test-existence
```

which may be or may be not related. Also, the app successfully opens the file directly from the AirDrop or if the file is moved to the app folder.

To reproduce, please see the [sample project](https://github.com/mgontar/so-ios-file-access-issue) (use *.txt files to be opened by the app).

Please advice if this is normal behavior, and if so, please direct to the appropriate documentation. If it's not, please advice if the fix is possible.

Comment: "app cannot access the downloaded files" & "app successfully opens the file directly if the file is moved to the app folder". So my guess is that you are trying to access files that were downloaded and saved to Files.app. In that case this link may be helpful - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories

Comment: @Kirow thank you for your help, it really resolves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the option `Supports opening documents in place` in the info.plist of your application.

When you use this option, you have to explicitly *ask* for access to the file from the url using security scoping, so changing the code to access the file to something kinda like:

```
let isSecuredURL = url.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() == true
let result = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url.path)

NSLog("File %@ %@", url.path, result ? "exists" : "not exists")

if (isSecuredURL) {
    url.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
}
```

Will address the issue.